# Parsing an XML with two same child nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a situation here where I need to parse the following xml:

```
<Attributes>
    <Map>
        <entry key="band" value="25" />
        <entry key="triggerSnapshots">
            <value>
                <Map>
                    <entry key="AttributeChange">
                        <value>
                            <Attributes>
                                <Map>
                                    <entry key="band" value="45" />
                                </Map>
                            </Attributes>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry key="ManagerTransfer" value="7262079" />
                    <entry key="needsCreateProcessing">
                        <value>
                            <Boolean>true</Boolean>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                </Map>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </Map>
</Attributes>
```

Questions:

1. In the above xml I need to pickup the value for the `band=25` entry key and not `band=45` entry key. When I parse my xml using:

   `NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");`

I first get band value as `25` and store it in map, then when I get band value as `45` the band value `25` in the map gets overwritten by `45`. I only need to parse the xml in a way that I get the band value as `25` and not as `45`.

Comment: if xml is not large, then I recommend XPath parser..in which you can put the whole path like 

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
map = (String)xpath.evaluate("/Attributes/Map/entry/value/Map", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

Comment: Is there a limit for this nesting ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put `doc.getElementsByTagName("entry").item(0)`
as this will get the first item that is "entry". But this wouldn't be the best way to go.

Might be best to look at XPath and get the specific XML nodes and values that you want `xpath.compile("/Attributes/Map/entry")`

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource input = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(input);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile("/Attributes/Map/entry[@key='band']/@value");
System.out.println(expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

[More on XPath here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)